# Repeating shape as a background-image

Tags: html, css

I created a .png file that I want to use as a background-image to repeat across the screen as a separator between sections.

I've tried using img, background-img, added it to a new (div). tried using (CSS} adding the img url with repeat-x. nothing seems to work.

```
/* with CSS 3 */
    <div class="divider">
      <img src="../../../assets/bgimg.png" height="80" alt="">
      </div>

/* with CSS 3 */
     .divider{
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
       background: url(http://localhost:4200/assets/bgimg.png);

}
```

This is my latest attempt

No error messages, the img appears but does not repeat.

Comment: background-repeat should be after background

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That didnt work

Comment: @Vilaggio I left a solution that's gotten two upvotes, so there's a good chance that it works. If it helps don't forget to leave the green checkmark! Hope it helps!

Comment: in all the cases you need to add it after. it's not meant to fix your issue but it a general advice because if you put it before it won't get considered because background will override it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears that you might need to add width and height to your divider. Plus you need to set the size of the image using css. I don't know exactly how you want it, but here's a Codepen link that has the code and might have the result you're looking for.

```
.divider{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dB3Dvgf3VIglusoGJAfpNUAANhTXW8K9mvIsiIPkhJUAbAKGKJcEMPTf0mkSexzLM5o=w300);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvQaWX

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I set the width to 90% and it looks great! If I had two of the same images, just different colors could I achieve the same results with the colors alternating?

Comment: No I don't think that would work with this solution. However, if you were to make both images into one image (each image positioned directly next to each other), then yes, this solution would work! I'm glad this helped, don't forget to mark this question correct and leave a green checkmark!

Comment: Here's the code I attempted with the 2 images side by side                         
        .divider{
    height: 60px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-image: url(http://localhost:4200/assets/bgimg1.png), url(http://localhost:4200/assets/bgimg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
  }

Comment: That's a great idea and a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: Dumb question? Brand new here, how do I leave a green check mark?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked. There should be a little grey checkmark at the top left of my answer, under the upvote and downvote buttons. If you click on it, it should turn green! :)